# Auth Services for Node.js Microservices and Vue3 Frontend - Seeking Guidance

Tags: node.js, vue.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm currently setting up a new system involving Node.js microservices in the backend and a Vue3 frontend as well as an mobile app. I've been diving into authentication and authorization options and stumbled upon Keycloak and Zitadel.

Keycloak’s documentation feels like a bad tangled web, and Zitadel seems promising but lacks docs or support for Vue/Node.js.

I'd love to hear from anyone who's navigated this territory. Any recommendations for solid services with clearer documentation and perhaps some implementation insights for Vue and Node.js integration would be golden. Or if you achieved something similar with Zitadel or KeyCloak using Vue.js and Node.js and you could give me some tipps, that would be awesome

Thanks a bunch for any help or advice you can offer!

Comment: Hi,

Please take a look at this new Vue.js guide by ZITADEL - https://zitadel.com/docs/examples/login/vue

And this is the Node.js guide - https://zitadel.com/docs/examples/secure-api/nodejs-nestjs

Hope these will help!